# Qt issue compiling Wireshark 1.99: invalid conversion from ‘const QMetaObject* const*’ to ‘const QMetaObject**’

Tags: qt, compilation, installation, ubuntu-14.04, wireshark

I'm trying to get a compiled version of wireshark on Ubuntu14.04 but I'm stuck at the `make` moment with the following error message:

```
  ...
  MOC      qcustomplot.moc.cpp
  CXX      qcustomplot.moc.o
qcustomplot.moc.cpp:4048:1: error: invalid conversion from ‘const QMetaObject* const*’ to ‘const QMetaObject**’ [-fpermissive]
 };
 ^
qcustomplot.moc.cpp:5020:1: error: invalid conversion from ‘const QMetaObject* const*’ to ‘const QMetaObject**’ [-fpermissive]
 };
 ^
make[2]: *** [qcustomplot.moc.o] Erreur 1
```

Some steps before getting the error:

- I followed the building guide: https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/ChSrcBuildFirstTime.html : `./autogen.sh; ./configure; make`
- installed the dependencies: `apt-get install autoconf autogen libtool automake bison flex qtbase5-dev libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-dev libpcap0.8-dev build-essential checkinstall libcurl4-openssl-dev libqt4-dev-bin libqt4-dev qt-sdk`

Here is my `./configure` output's end:

```
The Wireshark package has been configured with the following options.
                    Build wireshark : yes
                Build wireshark-gtk : yes (with GTK+ 3)
                       Build tshark : yes
                      Build tfshark : no
                     Build capinfos : yes
                      Build captype : yes
                      Build editcap : yes
                      Build dumpcap : yes
                     Build mergecap : yes
                   Build reordercap : yes
                    Build text2pcap : yes
                      Build randpkt : yes
                       Build dftest : yes
                     Build rawshark : yes
                        Build echld : no

   Save files as pcap-ng by default : yes
  Install dumpcap with capabilities : no
             Install dumpcap setuid : no
                  Use dumpcap group : (none)
                        Use plugins : yes
       Use external capture sources : yes
                    Use Lua library : yes
                   Build rtp_player : yes
             Build profile binaries : no
                   Use pcap library : yes
                   Use zlib library : yes
               Use kerberos library : yes (MIT)
                 Use c-ares library : yes
               Use GNU ADNS library : no (using c-ares instead)
                Use SMI MIB library : yes
             Use GNU crypto library : yes
             Use SSL crypto library : no
           Use IPv6 name resolution : yes
                 Use gnutls library : yes
     Use POSIX capabilities library : yes
                  Use GeoIP library : yes
                     Use nl library : no
              Use SBC codec library : no
```

Some work around:

- I do a `rm -rf builddir` and `make clean` between each new compilation
- I get the same error trying to compile 1.22 version
- I followed the instructions on a Ubuntu14.04 clean VM, and it worked perfectly !
- I made a diff between `dpkg -l | grep qt` on the VM and my first environment and `apt-get autoremove` the result

I'm running out of ideas... does someone have a trick or a way to search ?

Thanks !

Comment: Maybe it's conflicting agains other Qt versions you've installed?

Comment: I do not suspect Qt conflict that much: I uninstalled packets that were "in excess" comparing to my VM

Answer (score 0):

run [ldconfig](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ldconfig) after the dependencies are installed.

```
$:sudo ldconfig -v
```

> creates the necessary links and cache to the most recent shared
>   libraries

then hopefully the correct qt library will be referenced.

Comment: Thanks for your interest, sadly ldconfig wasn't enough ! I'm still stuck at the same error..